# Why is my cache not being updated as my database is updated?

Tags: node.js, express, caching, redis

I am implementing Redis in my nodejs REST API but as I am new to Redis, I am experiencing some issues.
I´ve successfully created a client, and my date is being stored in cache but the cache is never being updated.

What I understood by reading the docs is that my first request is gonna be to the database, and store the data in cache, so that as I make more request, then the responses I get are from cache, generating a better performance. But what I want is that as my database is updated with new data, or some rows are deleted, my API should do the request once again to the database with the updated database, and therefore update the cache.

So this is my route I am testing in:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/profiles
```

And this is my method in my controller:

```
exports.getProfiles = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const redis = require('redis');
    const url = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
    const client = redis.createClient(url);
    await client.connect();

    const cached = await client.get('profiles');
    
    if(cached) {
        console.log('Profiles cached');
        res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(cached));
        return;
    }

    const profiles = await Profile.findAll();
    console.log('Profiles not cached');
    res.status(200).json(profiles);

    
    client.SETEX('profiles',  3600, JSON.stringify(profiles));
});
```

When I first started the redis server I had four `profiles` and they were successfully stored in cache.

Now I added more `profiles` to my DB, but I am still getting the original 4 `profiles` from cache, instead of the newest data.

I´ve tried lowering the expiration time but didn´t work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1- The first thing you can do, is to decrease the ttl, right now, your ttl is 3600 seconds which is 1 hour, so if you check the results before 1 hour, you don't get the new results

2- the second thing you can do is to save data in the cache when new data is inserted in database. if you have an endpoint for updating the db, always clear the cache or save new data in cache on updates, to always have correct data in the cache.